# How to collapse buttons in xcode cocoa mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbutton

Question in short: How to collapse a button?

Question in long: I have an empty app with three push buttons that are populated in a row. When resizing window down I would like the button that is getting hidden to collapse to a lower row and vice versus.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't call that collapsing. I'd call it wrapping, just like text wraps. What have you tried? Where did you encounter trouble? Are your buttons uniform in size and spacing? You could use a collection view (`NSCollectionView`), which lays out items in a grid across one row and then the next row, etc. Other than that, you'd have to manually code the logic to position the buttons as the window changed size.

Comment: It's actually horizontal stacking, there is NSStackView and i find some custom class to do that https://gist.github.com/schwa/1867775

Comment: @diimdeep No, it's really not. Neither NSStackView nor the code you linked do what ShaunArchibald is asking. Ken's suggestions are the best - if all your buttons are the same size, use a collection view or roll your own solution. There's no easy way that makes for a reasonably-sized answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Ken, diimdeep and Joshua, I really appreciate it.

Yes the buttons are uniform in size and spacing and each button performs a different action.

I understand that the NSCollectionView will probably be the best bet.

I have searched how to do this online however the apple sample code is outdated and others are too complicated for a beginner :(, do you guys happen to know any guides that could help me?